# Tomcat/Java Error - org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager

Tags: java, tomcat

I spent two days on this issue ! Do not have any Java experience. Thought of asking you experts and helpful folks !
I have googled a lot on this but so far unsuccessful to fix the problem. Requesting help ! What I need to know is how to troubleshoot this problem.

I am trying to migrate a web application from RHEL 4 server to RHEL 5 Server. This is invoked by clients from a web browser. I installed tomcat, java etc. on my RHEL 5 test server and copied /var/www from the prod server .Most of the the things work under RHEL-5.

But there is an icon "logbook search" When I click on it, my web browser displays following -

```
HTTP Status 500 - 
________________________________________
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager
    org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager.newInstance(DTMManager.java:135)
    org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:100)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil.valueOf(XPathUtil.java:461)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ExprSupport.doStartTag(ExprSupport.java:64)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ExprTag.doStartTag(ExprTag.java:62)
    org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspx_meth_x_005fout_005f0(search_jsp.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f0(search_jsp.java:688)
    org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:110)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
________________________________________
Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely incompatibilities on the Java classpath.  It sounds like you're simply trying to migrate this application on to a new host and OS - neither of which should cause this.  You need to check the Java and Tomcat versions on each.  Have they changed?  If so, try starting with identical versions for each - as they existed on the RHEL 4 instance.

Also, how is Tomcat started?  Check the `$CLASSPATH` environment variable for each process, and ensure that it is identical between both the old and the new instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: Hello ziesemer. Thanks for your help. Yes, java and tomcat versions are different on the new RHEL server. This is from tomcat startup script -

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_29
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/tomcat
I will find out all the files which contain word "CLASSPATH" and will see what those contain. Will also report back the progress later. Thank you

Answer (score -4):

just add an exclusion of xalan

[image]

but first U should find out where it is by idea

[image]